# OAuth 2.0 Authorization server

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, azure, oauth-2.0

I have a REST service implemented by ASP.Net WebApi, a WPF client application that consume this service.
Every user have a UserName/Password in stored in Azure Table storage. Now I want to implement an OAuth authorization server "**Resource Owner Password Flow**".

Now my question is: How can I implement an OAuth 2.0 "authorization server" in .net?

I found that DotNetOpenAuth and thinktecture can help, but I'm not sure about any of them.

[image: Resource Owner Password Flow]

Comment: I'm a newbie in oauth and don't know where to start. I just found two libraries that may help the first one is DotNetOpenAuth and the second  called thinktecture.

Answer (score 1):

The DotNetOpenAuth has a WPF example among many other helpful examples. The only disadvantage of the library is the lack of comprehensive documentation, however samples are great and easy to follow.

Comment: I don't ask for a WPF example, I'm asking for an authorization server.

Comment: The WPF example is a part of the complete example set, containing both an identity provider and a resource server.

Comment: Can I use DotNetOpenAuth now; or we have now a newer library to use?

Comment: @OttoBarrows: DotNetOpenAuth is still usable.